# How to modify variables outside of a function in PHP / better way to do something

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a script with the following part:

```
function checkDays($oldDate){
    // calculate time
    // Print table row style based on number of days passed 
    // (eg less than 1 week, 1 week, 2 weeks, 3weeks+)
}

//Some code
checkdays($value)
```

I would like to put a counter of how many records of each time period there is, the function itself is inside a loop, so its called for each row of the table, and I can't seem to access variables defined outside the function itself so I can change them (eg. put a counter at the top of the script and modify it from the function).

Some people say use global variables but I understand that is a risk and not recommended. Is there an easy way to access the variables from the function? Also, is there a better way to do what I'm doing here overall?

Answer (score 11):

**DO NOT BE TEMPTED TO USE globals**

You can pass variables by reference, this means the actual variable is passed rather than a copy of it:

```
$count = 0;

//Some code
checkdays($value, $count);
checkdays($value, $count);
checkdays($value, $count);

// This will output 3
echo $count;

// Use a & to pass by reference
function checkDays($oldDate, &$count){
    // Your code goes here as normal
    // Increment $count, because it was passed by reference the 
    // actual variable was passed
    // into the function rather than a copy of the variable
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: @gnur: It's just a meme. Globals are only impractical if they hold state which is accessed and modified from multiple divergent subfunctions. For config settings etc. they are perfectly fine.

Comment: I have yet to see a convincing reason why using the `global` keyword (or `$GLOBALS`) is such a bad thing, especially when the alternative you suggest is pass-by-reference, which introduces a new point of failure - forgetting to pass or mistyping the variable you pass.

Comment: I will say this: IN GENERAL it is considered bad form, when writing an application, to pollute the global namespace with all of your variables and functions -- this is why we have namespaces and OOP.  However, the solution proposed here is NO DIFFERENT from using the global keyword.  It still modifies a variable defined and accessed in the global scope.  It offers, in my opinion, no advantage over the `global` keyword other than the ability to use different variables as counters, which is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: you're still using a global variable. might as well use `global` to simplify it. or $GLOBALS['count']

Comment: From the PHP Manual on Variable Scope: "[A] true global variable imported inside a function scope with the global statement actually creates a reference to the global variable." (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) There is literally no difference between the two, the `global` keyword is simply a shortcut to do what you're doing without having to pass the counter as an argument every single time.

Comment: Globals are not all bad. But they are so often incorrectly used by newbies that batting the idea of them about is bad, especially when they are not fully explained and only given as a quick example. Giving a newbie access to globals will nearly always result in an application/site which is riddled with security holes. I am not saying the OP is a newbie to PHP, but they are a lot of PHP newbies on SO thus I feel the use of them is nearly always best avoided

Comment: @Dereleased Yes, it's not ideal when a function isn't pure as is the case here, but there's a big difference between using a param and a global. When you have a param, you can look at the function header and see exactly what it's modifying. When you access a global, you have no idea what the side effect is. Param is much less brittle: it has a local name right in the func header. With a global, the name could be anywhere in the code--if it gets renamed by the client, the function breaks, potentially in a subtle way, potentially far away in the codebase. Not good. Params document dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I think the risk you're referring to is with `register_globals`, which is something else entirely.

Inside the function, use the `global` keyword, e.g.

```
function myFunction($someParam) {
    global $counter;
    ++$counter;
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively, you can do what's called pass-by-reference to modify a variable in the outer scope that's passed to your function, e.g.

```
function myFunction($someParam, &$counter) {
    ++$counter;
    // do something
}
```

Note the ampersand.

More information is available at the [PHP Manual page about Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Won't this reset once the function runs through and is recalled the second time?

Comment: no, the `global` keyword means you're referencing a variable in the outermost (global) scope.  So, in essence, a global variable named `$counter` will be the one getting incremented in the first example.  Contrast with the `static` keyword used in the same way the `global` keyword is used here, which will maintain the value of a variable across multiple calls to the same function, but does not make it accessible to, nor does it modify, any outer scope, including the global scope.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably [create a class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and use [private properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) for storing the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pollute the global namespace with useless variables, you can define static members of functions, that persist beyond the scope of the function, but only exist within the scope of the function:

```
function myFunction($param)
{
  static $count;
  if (empty($count)) $count = 0;
  $count++;

  //rest of your function
}
```

<del>Unfortunately, I can't seem to find where this functionality is documented in the php docs.</del>
Found it: [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> I can't seem to access variables defined outside the function itself

I had missed this line.

If you're in an OOP paradigm, use an object to store the counter. Otherwise, global variables are the way to go, but not directly. If you're coding in a scripted paradigm, and you're using the latest version of PHP, use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to keep from polluting the root namespace's globals.

If you can't use namespaces, use pseudo-namespaces for *everything*. Instead of `function someFunction`, use `function projectName_someFunction`, or some combination thereof. That way you can combine multiple projects without worrying about using the wrong function. In that same manner, all global variables can then be stored as `$projectName_someVar`.

There are other methods for pseudo-namespacing your function/variable names.

The reason *not* to use global variables is that a global variable with a common name can easily be overwritten, and may be ambiguous: what does `$count` actually *count* in the global namespace?

Comment: The only problem I see with using `static` is that it's not accessible outside of the function, so if it's needed outside of the function then static won't work, barring you create a special way to call the function to get that value.

Comment: oooh, i missed the part where he wanted to access it out of the function. If he's not coding in an OOP paradigm, he should store it in a global variable. Namespacing, and pseudo-namespacing can be used to prevent the normal issues of global scope.

Comment: it would be better to make a class that has a static variable and a function to increment it.

Comment: @Arvin, only if he's using OOP for the project. Mixing and matching paradigms is liable to cause more issues than they would solve.